# Autoload configuration doesn't load MongoDB classes

Tags: php, mongodb, mamp

I have MAMP 1.9 on MAC OSX 10.8.2 using PHP 5.3
I installed MongoDB and the PHP extension mongo.so and added it to my php.ini.

I can run the MongoDB on the console and my phpinfo says MongoDB support is enabled but I cannot run the following PHP script.

`<?php $connection = new MongoClient(); ?>`

PHP comes up with a fatal error:

`Class 'MongoClient' not found`

Something seems to be wrong with the autoload configuration of my MAMP (or the extension installation).

Comment: Did you restart Apache? Did you add the extension to the php.ini file in your Apache directory?

Comment: Yes sure, phpinfo says it's enabled - i don't think this is a MongoDB problem, I believe PHP simply doesn't find the include path to the Mongo Classes - btw: where are those usually?

Comment: The strange thing is if i run this ...

`$connection = new Mongo();`

...it says:

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message 'connecting to failed: Invalid argument' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mongo.php:4 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mongo.php(4): Mongo->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mongo.php on line 4`

Doesn't that mean PHP knows somehow where the Mongo classes are?

Comment: `echo extension_loaded("mongo") ? "loaded\n" : "not loaded\n";exit;` prompts "loaded". I have a feeling it's a version problem. I read that MongoClient is a class that's been added in November 2012.

Comment: Yes you are using an old version of the driver, unfortunately the docs have been replaced with solely the new version...the extension should be upgradable through pecl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sammaye mentioned in the comments above, it looks like you're simply running an older version of the driver. You can obtain the current version by either dumping `Mongo::VERSION` or the returned value from `phpversion('mongo')`. Instructions for installing/upgrading the drive via PECL are also [documented](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.osx); however, we no longer have pre-compiled versions available on GitHub (GitHub will soon be removing repository downloads, although we've recently begun publishing the Windows builds to S3).

Comment: Thank you, yes it was due to the driver version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue because I was changing wrong php.ini file. So I ran the below command

> echo phpversion('mongo');

and took `Loaded Configuration File` which was  /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/conf/php.ini and changed it.

Restarted Apache and it worked.yay!!!